# Can Html5 audio player play more then one song

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio

I'm using php glob() to get a list of the songs in a folder 
then use the shuffle() to shuffle the songs 
then use the foreach loop to loop through the songs.
but I can only get on song to play. I'm trying to get it to play
one song then when one song is over start another song automatically
Iv done a lot of googling but cant seem to find any thing is this only possible
with icecast? all post my code below

```
          <!DOCTYPE HTML>
          <html>


          <head>
          <title>ymp</title>

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

         </head>
          <body>
          <h1>YMP RADIO</h1>
          <?php require ("dropmenu.html"); ?>




           <?php     

            $music = glob("songs/*");  // get all files in the music directory
            shuffle($music);
            foreach ($music as $song){           // try and loop a random songs

            print <<<WTF

            <audio id="player" src="$song" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
            <audio id="player" src="$song" type="audio/ogg"></audio>

             WTF;

             }
             var_dump($song);
             ?>

             <div> 
             <table border="1px" >
             <tr>

             <td class="tdpage" >
             <img src="ymplogo5.jpg" alt=""  />
         <p><button  class="botton";   onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
         <button     class="botton";   onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button>
        <button     class="botton";   onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume+=0.1">Volume up </button>
       <button     class="botton";   onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume-=0.1">Volume down</button>

    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>    
    </div> 

    <br /><br /><br />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo upon copy/paste or not, but the ending `WTF;` [can not have any space or anything before it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: I think it was the copy and paste i have no errors just the script is not working like i thought it would

Comment: Also, [you can't have duplicate `id` in a document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ugh, so if I understand your question correctly, you seem to be wanting to implement user interaction feature (playlists) via server side processing (php). Unfortunately this won't work. Your php only provides the urls of the songs. The rest of the work lies on client side work like js. You can do the following (but let me warn you it's not as simple as I think you take it to be)

- Take the url list from php and echo it in a script tag and store it in a js variable.
- Then use js to play the first song (keep in mind we will only be using one audio tag)
- Then listen for an event listener that tells the js when the song ends, and when it does, play the next song (replace the url with the new one).

Most of your work will be in js and not in php. And even when you do this, this will only make a bare bones media player.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to start to learn more about JavaScript this is going to take a while to do lol but thank you for clearing this up